# Print "custom label" for indicating type of post in the front end for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a blog with different custom post types ("books", "interviews", "recipes", "events", etc...). those are all appearing in the home page with same format like a grid. I would like to print in the front end a "label" customized possibly, representing the kind/content of post.

For example:
if the post is a CPT "Book", I want to show in the grid cell "looking for a book?"
if the post is a CPT "Recipe", I want to show on same position, for specific post "hungry?"
etc...

Can you maybe help me in this? I guess I need some PHP code and set it with Elementor, but I am not a developer... :(

Thanks for any help.
Mario.

I have been asked in comment to put a screenshot. this is a fake grid taken from internet (I know, ugly layout), presenting in descending order by date all posts, very different in domain (different custom post types), which I am able to do it. What I need is, depending by Post Type, to add a slogan like "watch the movie" or "hungry?" or "Interview with...", a static string totally dependent by the type of CPT.
[fake sample from internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02snW.gif)

Further integration to explain the context.
See the current home page of my site: [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q2Mc2vtrIr66AxoNcC0jsoPbVmvnlM9M/view?usp=sharing)
You see two "posts" in a grid (3 columns, published with "post" widget in elementor and a custom skin. This custom skin is linked to a "loop" template created with "ele custom skin". As you see by the pic, you have one post which is a recipe (custom post type "Recipe") and one is a book (custom post type is book). But here I can eventually find also a standard post. Now, when you see the "red dot", I would like to put a word, which is directly dependent by the post type:

- if "recipe" --> "Hungry?"
- if "book" --> "our book reviews"...
  etc...

---

as a sample I have in this link [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mkbg80ZL7wyUt0H4DvDKHtH57cIy9wnV/view?usp=sharing) for each loop in the grid, called using "shortcode" widget

```
[helloworld]
```

and coded in snippets plugin following portion of php code

```
function HelloWorldShortcode() {
    return '<p>Hello World!</p>';
}
add_shortcode('helloworld', 'HelloWorldShortcode');
```

Comment: Please edit your question and attach some screenshots to understand how your current view is and how you want it to be changed. Thanks

Comment: Hi @VijayHardaha, did it. I hope this clarifies....

Comment: That's still not helpful. However, I am assuming, that somehow you managed to show mixed posts from different post types in one section(generally this doesn't happen), you should show posts from one post type, but as you're showing posts from multiple post types.

Now I am assuming that before the title you want to add a prefix or above the title you want to add a label and this label will be decided based on post type.

Comment: So if I am assuming everything correctly, then you'll have to customize the post grid that you're creating with elementor then you'll have to add a shortcode section.

then you'll have to code a shortcode and from the current post global object, you'll have to validate the type and return the desired string based on the match.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @VijayHardaha. I have further elaborated with explanation. Hope this helps now. Thanks a lot for you patience and assistance. Shortcode would be perfect, but I am not expert of programming. Can you address me to some material?

Comment: If you know basic programming, then First create a shortcode that returns "Hello World" and use it in your grid, then test if it's showing the "hello World" in your red dot area or not. then I can provide proper shortcode code to get the text based on post type. but before that first, verify that the shortcode can be used to display the things or not.

Comment: Hi @VijayHardaha. Done using "snippet" plugin. thank you again. here the link [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mkbg80ZL7wyUt0H4DvDKHtH57cIy9wnV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: edit your question and append the shortcode code that you have created and used. I will modify the code then you can replace it.

Comment: Thank you very much @VijayHardaha. I have appended to the mail post the portion of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, from this code shortcode will be `[vkh_display_post_tagline]`

```php
/**
 * Custom shortcode to display the tagline by the post type.
 */
/**
 * Custom shortcode to display the tagline by the post type.
 */
function vkh_display_tagline_by_post_type() {
    global $post;

    if ( ! $post || empty( $post ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Uncomment the next line for debugging and to know if we're getting post type of not.
    // return $post->post_type;

    $heading = '';

    switch ( $post->post_type ) {
        case 'recipe':
            $heading = __( 'Hungry?', 'your-text-domain' );
            break;

        case 'book':
            $heading = __( 'Our book reviews', 'your-text-domain' );
            break;

        // Add more cases following above examples.

        default:
            // If you have to assign anything default when a case doesn't match
            // then write that here.
            $heading = '';
            break;
    }

    // When heading is not empty return heading within the html tag.
    if ( ! empty( $heading ) ) {
        return '<h4 class="post-tagline">' . esc_html( $heading ) . '</h4>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'vkh_display_post_tagline', 'vkh_display_tagline_by_post_type' );
```